# Laravel Eloquent orWhere not working as expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This Eloquent query does not seem to be working as expected.

If I pass in a term then category then manufacturer it works as expected, but only entering a manufacturer yields zero results and likewise with manufacturer.

Here is my url...
/products?term=12&category=2&manufacturer=3

Here is the dump of toSql()
"select * from `products` where `id` = ? or `model` like ? or `category_id` = ? or `manufacturer_id` = ?"

```
        $term = $request->input('term');
        $category = $request->input('category');
        $manufacturer = $request->input('manufacturer');

        $products = Product::orWhere('id', $term)
               ->orWhere('model', 'like', "%{$term}%")
               ->orWhere('category_id', $category)
               ->orWhere('manufacturer_id', $manufacturer)
               ->get();
```

Stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what if `url... /products?manufacturer=3` ?

Comment: Interesting, if i just pass manufacturer or category in the url it returns all results, does that mean it is never reaching the orWhere calls?

Comment: is there any one argument is compulsory...?

Comment: Is there a way to only call ```->orWhere('model', 'like', "%{$term}%")``` if term is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$term = $request->input('term');
$category = $request->input('category');
$manufacturer = $request->input('manufacturer');

$products = Product::where(function ($query) use ($request,$term,$category,$manufacturer) {
if($request->filled('term'))
   $query->orWhere('model', 'like', "%{$term}%")->orWhere('id', $term);
if($request->filled('category'))
   $query->orWhere('category_id', $category);
if($request->filled('manufacturer'))
   $query->orWhere('manufacturer_id', $manufacturer);

})->latest()
->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thank you Karan! This conditional logic worked with a little modification...